# iphone: Drawing over MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, mkmapview, android-mapview, draw

I'm attempting to draw polygons on a mapView. What I did was to add a transparent view on the main view, that matches the bounds of the mapView, and I draw over it. When I move the table it's ok, but when I zoom in and out the polygones 'bounce' on the Y axis (latitude) but the x axis is ok. What do you think?

BTW I tried to add the transparent view as a subview to the mapView but then it screwed up the  user interactions.

How can this be done? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post.  It's a little old but still works.  He shows how to draw a route over a MKMapView, which is similar.

The post is:  http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65

Comment: I use this with great success!